# ruby gsub not working

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

gsub is not working as expected...

I have a string `numbers`as following: `numbers="88 99"`

I want to replace the `space` with a `slash`. So i tried the following:

`numbers.gsub(/\s/,"/")` and got the following string: `88//99`

I get double slashes instead of one slash. Moreover, if i want to do something like:

`numbers.gsub(/\s/,"  /  ")`

I can't ! Since the additional spaces disappear...

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `numbers.gsub(/\s+/,"  /  ")`? Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

`gsub()` is working fine. Using the example you posted:

```
$ irb
>> numbers="88 99"
=> "88 99"
>> numbers.gsub(/\s/, '/')
=> "88/99"
```

Your actual string evidently has multiple whitespace chars, and each one is replaced with a slash. @zishe gave the solution to replace a sequence of multiple whitespace chars:

```
>> numbers="88  99"
=> "88  99"
>> numbers.gsub(/\s+/, '/')
=> "88/99"
```

`\s+` matches a sequence of one or more whitespace characters.

Comment: It worked, but not when i want to add extra spaces around the slash !

Comment: Need to show the code you're using. Can't see that problem.